# How do I decompress a .astc file with an additional .ccz extension? How do I view .lta files?

Tags: android, decompress

> This is crossposted from reg. stack overflow. I was referred here.
>   This will have more updates, however.

First, full disclosure: I'm very new to coding and very new to file dissecting, but its something I anticipate studying in school very soon, so please pardon my ignorance in future interactions.

As a project I've decided to dissect the files of a mobile app I greatly enjoy. This app is **Futurama: Worlds of Tomorrow**. I'm a big fan of the cartoon, even spent money on the stuff, so I figured it was natural for me to pick.

Extracting the .apk file was easy, I found some of the assets they use in the game, like the music, the soundbytes, and some .pngs. All simple stuff.

However there are two files I'm absolutely baffled by: files with an .astc.czz extension and .lta files, the developers informed me that those are animation files.

Allow me to go into what I know and what I don't know:

## Filename.astc.czz

Example file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuj392gfurvil00/BR0001-dialogue7-000%402x.astc.ccz?dl=0)
I recognize .astc as a compression file and was informed that .astc files are common for mobile games. Fair enough, but the real extension is .czz, the "real" extension of the file leads me to dead end. I've found the **ASTC Evaluation Codec
by ARM-Software** on github so I tried that. I changed the extension to .astc and then tried keeping .czz but the codec gives me an error every time. This is where I show my ignorance, I didn't know the right way to do this so I'm showing you every combination of what I tried. I replaced my name with **user**.

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32
λ astcenc -d C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32\AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.astc C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32\AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.tga
File C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32\AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.astc not recognized

C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32
λ astcenc -d AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.astc AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.tga
File AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.astc not recognized

C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32
λ astcenc -d C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32\AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.astc.czz C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32\AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.tga
Failed to open file C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32\AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.astc.czz

C:\Users\user\Downloads\astc-encoder-master\Binary\Win32
λ astcenc -d AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.astc.czz AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.tga
Failed to open file AC0001-dialogue1-003@2x.astc.czz
```

No success there.

So then I learned that .CZZ files are apparently associated with **visECAD Viewer**  and I downloaded that and the .astc.czz files became associated with the program. I tried opening them but visECAD says it cant open them because they are "outdated." So that's another dead end.

I was told to use Unix's file command too, and all I got was "data":

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ file BR1.astc.ccz -b data ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ file BR1.astc.ccz BR1.astc.ccz: data ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ file BR1.astc.ccz -i -b application/octet-stream; charset=binary ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ file BR1.astc.ccz -z BR1.astc.ccz: data ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ file -z BR1.astc.ccz BR1.astc.ccz: data
```

Right, so that's all I know.

## Filename.lta

Example file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tficytd7avy4fpq/BR0001-dialogue3.lta?dl=0)
Out of curiosity I've actually emailed the developers about this file (and the astc ones too) and they said those are the animation files of the game. They couldn't send me a viewer, which is perfectly fine, but I don't even know what .lta could be. I think it has something to do with Maya, but that's all I got. Any insight would be appreciated, the animations are great and I would love to see them.

For full disclosure here are snippets of what the developers sent me:

> Those strange file types are actually compressed files (like
>   ".astc.ccz"). Different devices use different compression methods, so
>   we support many types to maintain low storage and memory usage. Some
>   devices don't use compression and just use .png versions of the same
>   file names.
>
> The .lta files are the game's animations. I wish I could help you out
>   with viewing them, but there's no way for me to send you a viewer. :(

Well that's all folks, sorry it was so long, and thank you so much in advance. I'm grateful already!

Answer (score 1):

since these formats seem to be custom to the game, I suspect there is no other way than disassembling/decompiling the game code to see how they're processed.